# Limit of $\frac{y^4\sin(x)}{x^2+y^4}$ when $(x,y) \to (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to find the following limit when $x,y$ tend towards $0$. I *think* the limit doesn't exist (thanks to Wolfram Alpha), but all I can find no matter what path I use (I've tried $y=x², x=y^2, x=0, y=0$) is that the limit equals $0$ (because of the $sin(0)$). Any tips?

$$\frac{y^4\sin(x)}{x^2+y^4}$$

Comment: Hint: $0 \leq\dfrac{y^4}{x^2+y^4} \leq 1$ for every $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$. (And so the limit exists...)

Comment: The reason Wolfram Alpha tells you that the limit doesn't exist is because Wolfram Alpha considers complex values by default;  its results say that the "value may depend on x, y path **in complex space**" (bolding mine).  In particular, if you allow $x$ and $y$ to be pure imaginary, then the function is divergent when $x^2 = - y^4 \neq 0$, and the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{y^4\sin x}{x^2+y^4}=\frac{\sin x}{x}\frac{y^4x}{x^2+y^4}$$

then recall that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\to 1$.

To show that $\frac{y^4x}{x^2+y^4} \to 0$ we can use inequalities or as an alternative by $u=x$ and $v=y^2$

$$\frac{y^4x}{x^2+y^4}=\frac{uv^2}{u^2+v^2}=r\cos \theta\sin^2 \theta \to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Using AM-GM then we get
$$\frac{x^2+y^4}{2}\geq |x|y^2$$ so $$\frac{y^4|x|}{x^2+y^4}\le \frac{y^2}{2}$$ and this tends to zero if $y$ tends to zero.
We also have used that $$|\sin(x)|\le 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $|x|,|y| <1$,  $x,y$ real.

$0\le \left | \dfrac{y^4 \sin x }{x^2+y^4} \right | \le $

$\dfrac{y^4|x|}{x^4 + y^4} \le$

$\dfrac{(y^4+x^4)|x|}{x^4+ y^4}= |x| \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

Choose $\delta =\epsilon.$

Used : $|\sin x| \le |x|$